# What is the difference between add_artist or add_patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing

I am trying to find the difference between add_artist method and add_patch but I can't figure out.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.3))

plt.show()
```

And

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.3))

plt.show()
```

Give the exact same behaviour... Maybe these two methods are doing the same but I am not sure ? Which one do I need to use if I want to draw something ?

Kind regards,

Comment: add_artist isn't really intended for data, but for annotations to the data.

Comment: So it's the same thing with a different name for a different goal ?

Comment: One difference I have come across is that `add_patch` changes the data limits where as `add_artist` does not. For example, if you increase the radius to 0.6 in your MWE, and call `ax.autoscale_view()` before `plt.show()`, then the x and y limits will be adjusted in the first plot but not in the second.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.